# Sending PUT request in Nuxt3 with oh my fetch

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I try send put request in public api. When I send, my data doesn't update.

my code:

```js
<template>
<div class="mt-20 mb-32 px-20 mx-aute gap-20" data-scroll-section>
  <div class="mt-20 mb-20">
      <form>
      <label>Enter Title</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="title"/>
      <button class="ng-bt-pri" @click="update">Send Message</button>
      </form>
  {{title}}
  </div>                        
  {{data}}                                     
</div>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
import { $fetch } from 'ohmyfetch'
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

var title = ref("");

const update = async() => await $fetch( "https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products/1", {
        headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
        method: "put",
        body: {
          'title': title
        }
    } );
const {data} = await useFetch('https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products/1')
</script>
```

and api documentation:

https://fakeapi.platzi.com/doc/products#update-a-product

Comment: Posting code images is forbidden here, so plese redo that with actual text. Also, try to change the `body` by a `data` and also check your network tab if you're properly sending things from your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of a `ref` in the script section, you have to use the `value` property.

I.e. instead of

```
        body: {
          'title': title
        }
```

use

```
        body: {
          'title': title.value
        }
```